# No serializer found for JSONObject while returning JSON for GET request using Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey to implement REST apis. Other than all the endpoints, I wanted to create a about page that lists all the endpoints and their usages.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response displayInfo() {
    JSONObject json = createInfoJson();
    return Response.ok(json).build();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////
public static JSONObject createInfoJson() {
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
    jo1.put("baseurl", "/tests/");
    jo1.put("description", "Basic Information page");
    jo1.put("example", "/tests/");
    ja.put(jo1);

    JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject();
    jo2.put("baseurl", "/tests/sendmsg");
    jo2.put("description", "Run Kafka Test");
    jo2.put("example", "/tests/sendmsg?count=100");
    ja.put(jo2);
    ja.put(jo2);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("name", "Kafka Messaging Test");
    json.put("endpoints", ja);

    return json;
}
```

When I hit the about page in a browser, I got the following error:

```
No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

What is the correct way to return a JSONObject object from Jersey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to serialize JSONObject to JSON, it doesn't work this way (error explains why). But you have at least two options:

1. Serialize `json` to String:

   ```
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response displayInfo() {
       JSONObject json = createInfoJson();
       return Response.ok(json.toString()).build();
   }
   ```
2. Create Model/POJO for your response and use it instead JSONObject.